# AutoCAD: Opening a drawing/database from memory, instead of a file

Tags: drawing, autocad, dwg, objectarx

I am working on a plugin that would enable AutoCAD to open my encrypted drawings. I would like to avoid having to decrypt the drawing to a dwg file on disk. However, the APIs for opening a drawing in AutoCAD all seem to work only with filepaths. Is there any other way to load a drawing/database in AutoCAD, that does not involve having a dwg file on the hard drive?

What has caught my attention was the

`AcDbDatabase::readDwgFile(AcDwgFileHandle * pDwgFile, ...)`

function, but I was unable to find any information on the AcDwgFileHandle class. If it was just a wrapper for Win32 HANDLE or something, it would easily solve my problems.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "file in memory", can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already answered [there](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/objectarx/opening-a-drawing-database-from-memory-instead-of-a-file/td-p/6293121) AcDwgFileHandle is internal class (not handle wrapper).

With Dependency Wolker we can find some functions in acdb19.dll:

```
enum Acad::ErrorStatus AcDwgFileHandle::close(class AcDwgFileHandle * &)
enum Acad::ErrorStatus AcDwgFileHandle::open(wchar_t const *,class AcDwgFileHandle * &,int)
class AcDwgFileHandle * AcDwgFileHandle::open(wchar_t const *,int,enum Acad::ErrorStatus *,int (*)(int,int,int,int))
```

But unfortunately these functions are useless for you.

You may think to change dwgIn dwgOut somehow. So .dwg will be on disk but already encrypted.